# rails create pages by hash with nested resources

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BDOG.jpg)

as image, i'd like to make page with nested resources.

my plan is

1. register user
2. create tour(request input informations by params)
3. if @tour.tour_days(params) value is over 1
4. create day pages as much as the number of user put into tour_day params

so i want to create page like(if 1user create first tour and put 3 into tour_day)
localhost:3000/tours/1/days/1
localhost:3000/tours/1/days/2
localhost:3000/tours/1/days/3

(if 1user create second tour and put 2 into tour_day)
localhost:3000/tours/2/days/1
localhost:3000/tours/2/days/2

i'd like to create these pages by automatically 
when user put number into tour_day and click submit button from tour_view

i've done create nested resources and throw data but i can't make clearly.. ;(
the reason i nest resources and create additional controller(day_controller) is afterwords i'd like to add recommendation function(recommendation for whom couldn't make schedule)...
actually i'd like to make page like airbnb(creating room process)
(Am i doing right process??)

tour_controller

```
class ToursController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_tour, only:[:show, :edit, :update]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except:[:show]


  def index
    @tours = current_user.tours
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @tour = current_user.tours.build

  end


  def create
    @tour = current_user.tours.build(tour_params)

    i = 0
    if @tour.save
      redirect_to new_tour_day_path(@tour.id, @day), notice: "Saved Your Tour Courses"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @tour.update(tour_params)
      redirect_to edit_tour_day_path(@tour.id, @day), notice: "Updated Your Tour Courses"
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private
  def set_tour
    @tour = Tour.find(params[:id])
  end

  def tour_params
    params.require(:tour).permit(:tour_title, :tour_theme, :tour_summary, :tour_language, :tour_day, :tour_member, :tour_car, :tour_camera, :price)
  end

end
```

day_controller

```
class DaysController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_tour
  before_action :set_day, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except:[:show]

  def index
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @tour = current_user.tours.find(params[:tour_id])
    @day = @tour.days.build
  end

  def create
    @tour = current_user.tours.find(params[:tour_id])
    @day = @tour.days.build(day_params)

    if @day.save
      redirect_to edit_tour_day_path(@tour.id, @day), notice: "Saved Your Tour Courses"
    else
      render :new, notice: "Errors"
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @day.update(day_params)
      redirect_to edit_tour_day_path(@day), notice: "Updated Your Tour Courses"
    else
      redner :edit
    end
  end

  private

  def set_tour
    @tour = Tour.find(params[:tour_id])
  end

  def set_day
    @day = Day.find(params[:id])
  end

  def day_params
    params.require(:day).permit(:day_number)
  end
end
```

tour_view(test page)

```
<div class="container">
    <%= form_for @tour, :html => { multipart: true } do |f| %>
        <div class="col-md-3 select">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Maximum Tour Day</label>
                <%= f.select :tour_day, [["1",1], ["2",2], ["3",3], ["4",4]], prompt: "Select...", class: "form-control" %>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="actions">
            <%= f.submit "save", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        </div>
    <% end %>

</div>
```

day_view(test page)

```
<div class="container">
  <%= form_for [:tour, @day] do |f| %>
    <label>day_number</label>
    <%= f.text_field :schedule_, class: "form-control" %>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-primary"%>
    </div>
  <% end %>

</div>
```

** additionally
Inside of Day view
i'd like to create schedule like
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfqsv.jpg)

when i click an icon, the form appear and make detail tour schedule with ajax.
how can i approach to create this function??

----
this is my first project of web programming, im so confusing
plz... give me some(lots of) help... 

----
im using rails 5.0.0.1 and rails 2.3.1

Comment: Hi. I'd recommend either Michael Hartl's rails tutorial, or narrowing this down to one specific thing you don't understand. Please see the help center for guidance on asking a good question. Users are less likely to enter into broad questions.

Comment: 1. i wonder how can create id like tour1 has day1,day2.day3 & tour2 has day1,day2,day3
when i create days in nested with tour2 it started from day4, day5, day6
2. and when i want to make a list of tours and days, i couldn't get tour_id from days